# How to get device info (hardware IDs) on disconnect in Windows process callback?

Tags: c++, windows, notifications, device, handle

Using a Windows process callback for device changes, I'm able to setup a handle when a device arrives, which let's me look at it's device attributes like Hardware IDs in a simple way without having to do any device enumeration.

However, on a "device disconnect" the handle received is invalid, which seems right, since the device is no longer connected, but I can't look at the device attributes. Is there a way the handle can still be used?

```
DEV_BROADCAST_HDR* devHDR = reinterpret_cast<DEV_BROADCAST_HDR*>(lParam);
if (devHDR->dbch_devicetype == DBT_DEVTYP_DEVICEINTERFACE)
{
    DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE* devInterface = reinterpret_cast<DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE*>(lParam);
    DeviceHandle = CreateFile(devInterface->dbcc_name, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, NULL, NULL);
    if(DeviceHandle ==  != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE){
        // arrive gets here
    } else {
        // disconnect gets here
    }
}
```

Basically, since I can't get a valid handle on disconnect I can't get the hardware IDs and other data from the DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE struct. Is there another way to get the device hardware IDs on disconnect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a device connects, store the info you will need on disconnect in a map where you use something unique for the device as key.

When a device disconnects, use the key you get in the disconnect event to lookup the info in the map and then delete the entry.

Example:

```
using String = std::basic_string<TCHAR>;

// a struct with all the properties you'd like to use on disconnect
struct device_info {
    CHANGER_PRODUCT_DATA cpd; // just an example
    String something;
};

int main() {
    // a map where the device_name is the key and device_info the value
    std::unordered_map<String, device_info> devices;

    {   // on connect, create a device_info struct and fill it with the info you need on
        // disconnect
        DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE* devInterface =
            reinterpret_cast<DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE*>(lParam);
        String new_dev_name { devInterface->dbcc_name };

        device_info di{}; // store what you need from the opened device here
                          // and put it in the map
        devices.emplace(new_dev_name, di);
    }

    {   // on disconnect, find the entry in the map using the disconnected device_name
        DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE* devInterface =
            reinterpret_cast<DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE*>(lParam);
        String disc_dev_name{ devInterface->dbcc_name };

        auto fit = devices.find(disc_dev_name);

        if (fit != devices.end()) {
            // we found the device, extract it
            device_info disc_di = fit->second;
            // and erase it from the map
            devices.erase(fit);
            std::wcout << "\"" << disc_di.something << "\" disconnected\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this method. I was able to make it simpler for myself since I only need to compare the device path to the current device path associated with my user data used by the windows proc. The user data is dynamic so it works to auto connect to another device of the same hardware ids if the current device no longer exists.Thanks!

Comment: @karamazovbros Sounds great! Cheers!  I updated it a little to make more sense for anyone reading it later.

Answer (score 0):

Your method is not correct.

You must first check *wParam* and test if == **DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL** and == **DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE**

In **DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE** test, you will get *lParam* filled to get **DEV_BROADCAST_HANDLE**

Comment: I am using a switch with those cases. I'll check for a DEV_BROADCAST_HANDLE but how exactly can I get info from it?

Comment: @karamazovbros It depends on what kind of information you would like to obtain. You can't open the device obviously. If the info you need is not present in the `DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE` struct you get on disconnect, you need to store the information _before_ the disconnect - like I showed in my answer. If you don't get the handle of the disconnected device, use something else that is unique to the device to use as a key in the map.